# google map style airport runway

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On google maps, Airports usually has two colors:

- Lighter color representing whole airport terrain
- Darker color representing runway

While trying to style map, I found out that there is no way (as far as I know), to style both of them separately. There is only one constant for airport in [official API Refference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType), called `transit.station.airport`.

Is there any way to style airport runway in separation of whole airport terrain?

http://jsfiddle.net/rqvpQ/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you need to invert lightness and then play with color adjustments from there. I used the styled map wizard:

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

to play around with it and I don't guarantee color matching or anything here, but this is pretty close to inverted colors:

```
var style = [
    {
        "featureType": "transit.station.airport",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "invert_lightness": true
            },
            {
                "gamma": 9
            },
            {
                "hue": "#ff7700"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N9xpu/